# FTPLIB not able to access the DSNAME

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

This is simple , I am assuming some flaws at my end. So I am using **ftplib** to access the Mainframe. After entering through credentials, I have to go in a certain DSNAME and see the **list** of the files under it..

The Code :

```
ftp.dir("ABCD.TR.RTYP4573.REQW3024")
ftp.retrlines("LIST")
```

However I am getting error like :

```
error_perm: 550 No data sets found.
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head around here and there , I have finally found a solution. 
And I will try to be as verbose as I can since it might help others.

```
import ftplib

from ftplib import *

ftp = ftplib.FTP('xyz.tpt.com','abcdef','abcdef')

ftp.retrlines('LIST')

ftp.dir()
```

The last two commands gives the name of DSNAME's where you are currently.
Both can be used interchangingly (is it a word !!!! )

```
ftp.sendcmd('pwd')
```

Provides the name of "present working directory".

```
ftp.cwd("'PSQW.CV.RRRR67.RETY890'")
```

The above command will change the working direcoty. 
Please please use the **quotes** inside **quotes**.

```
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

See the file listing........